# Bit.ly retrieve url curl returns {"FORBIDDEN","resource":"bitlinks","description":"You are currently forbidden to access this resource."}

Tags: http, url, curl, url-shortener, bit.ly

I'm running a curl to retrieve a bit.ly url from my terminal and getting a forbidden error.

```
   curl \                                        
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}' \
    -X GET \
    https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/bit.ly/3fjIJ2P
```

error:

```
{"message":"FORBIDDEN","resource":"bitlinks","description":"You are currently forbidden to access this resource."}
```

I'm using the guide the API documentation: https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#getBitlink and yes I have created the short url.
Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using bitly /v3 path, they have moved on to /v4 so although I could create new links, I couldn't find them .